# Menu & Submenu Hover Both With Separate Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I think I've been overthinking this all day long. It shouldn't be this hard...

I have a div with the main menu it's child with the submenu. My initial problem was wanting to show the submenu horizontal instead of vertial with absolute positioning on the screen so I could put it where I want it. Now I have this mess, and I think overthinking the situation has lost me on it.

I just want to separate the submenu from the parent after hovering over parent, then keep it up as long as you're on the parent or submenu, and fade it out when you leave either, putting the submenu appended back to the parent. The logo gets faded out when hovering over a parent that has a submenu, and faded back in when the submenu fades out. What its doing now is fading back in the logo pretty much no matter what, and its really buggy when hovering on submenu, along with it just plain not staying when hovering over it sometimes.

If there's a better way to position this so I don't have to go through this mess, or just a better way overall, please point it out.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var inEle = false;
        var hideTimer;

        $('.sub-menu li a').css('display', 'inline-block');

        // do hover on main menu
        $('.uk-navbar-nav li a').hover(
            function() {
                // reset everything on new hover
                clearTimeout(hideTimer);

                // fade in the spire logo
                $('.logoimgcontainer img').stop(true, true).fadeIn(2000);

                inEle = true;

                // save the id if there is one to hide
                var subID = $('body').children('ul[class*="sub-menu"]').attr('id');
                // find the ul submenu and put it back on the div in the main menu, remove the placeholder id
                $('body').children('ul[class*="sub-menu"]').appendTo($(this).parent().parent().find('div[id*="'+subID+'"]')).removeAttr('id');
                // fade out the ul submenu
                $(this).parent().parent().find('div[id*="'+subID+'"]').find('ul').fadeOut(100);
                // find the div holding the ul submenu and take out its placeholder id
                $(this).parent().parent().find('div[id*="'+subID+'"]').removeAttr('id');

                //show submenu
                if ($(this).parent().find('div').hasClass('uk-dropdown')) {             
                    $('.logoimgcontainer img').stop(true, true).fadeOut(150);
                    $(this).parent().find('div').find('ul').appendTo('body').css({
                        'display' : 'inline-block',
                        'position' : 'absolute',
                            'left' : '0',
                            'right' : '0',
                            'top' : '90px',
                        'margin' : 'auto',
                        'width' : '300px',
                        'text-align' : 'center',
                        'z-index' : '150'
                    }).attr('id', $(this).text());
                    $(this).parent().find('div').attr('id', $(this).text());
                    $(this).parent().find('div').find('ul').fadeIn(1000);
                }
            }, function() {
                // do nothing here mkay
            }
        );

        // do hover out on main menu
        $('.uk-navbar-nav li').hover(
            function() {
                // do nothing here k
            },function() {
                // check if this item has a submenu
                if ($(this).find('div').hasClass('uk-dropdown')) {
                    // clear out the timer
                    clearTimeout(hideTimer);

                    var aID = $(this).find('a').text();

                    // go ahead and set it not in sub since it hovered out here
                    inEle = false;

                    // reset the timer
                    hideTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                        // make sure its not in the submenu
                        if (!inEle) {
                        //var checkUL = $('ul[id*="'+aID+'"]');
                        //if (!checkUL.is(":hover")) {
                           // hideTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                                // fade in the spire logo
                                $('.logoimgcontainer img').stop(true, true).fadeIn(2000);

                                // find the ul submenu and put it back on the div in the main menu, remove the placeholder id
                                $('ul[id*="'+aID+'"]').appendTo('div[id*="'+aID+'"]').removeAttr('id');
                                // fade out the ul submenu
                                $(this).find('div[id*="'+aID+'"]').find('ul').fadeOut(500);
                                // find the div holding the ul submenu and take out its placeholder id
                                $(this).find('div[id*="'+aID+'"]').removeAttr('id');

                            //}, 1000);
                        }else clearTimeout(hideTimer);  // still in the sub menu, clear the timer, handle in submenu
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        );

        // do hover in the submenu
        $('.sub-menu').hover(
            function() {
                // set were in the submenu now
                inEle = true;

                // take out the timer for the main menu
                clearTimeout(hideTimer);
            }, function() {
                // dont need the timeout anymore, not in submenu or main menu item
                clearTimeout(hideTimer);

                var ulID = $(this).attr('id');

                // set were out of the submenu
                inEle = false;
                hideTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                    //var checkUL = $('.uk-navbar-nav li a:contains("'+ulID+'")');
                    //if (!checkUL.is(":hover")) {
                    if (!inEle) {
                        // fade in the spire logo
                        $('.logoimgcontainer img').stop(true, true).fadeIn(3000);

                        // find the ul submenu and put it back on the div in the main menu, remove the placeholder id
                        $('body').find('ul[id*="'+ulID+'"]').appendTo($('.uk-navbar-nav li').find('div[id*="'+ulID+'"]')).removeAttr('id');
                        // fade out the ul submenu
                        $('.uk-navbar-nav li').find('div[id*="'+ulID+'"]').find('ul').fadeOut(500);
                        // find the div holding the ul submenu and take out its placeholder id
                        $('body').find('div[id*="'+ulID+'"]').removeAttr('id');
                    }else clearTimeout(hideTimer);  // still in the sub menu, clear the timer, handle in submenu
                }, 1000);
            }
        );
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend going with clicks instead of hovers, because hovers don't work on mobile devices (aka touch screens).  Rolling your own menu is kind of like reinventing the wheel these days.  I can recommend some good bootstrap based templates that already have menus built in and they even "magically" change into hamburgers on mobile devices.  However, maybe you are trying to learn and I have written some menus myself and one piece of advice on can give you is that you should use jquery and use mouseLeave instead of mouseOut.  mouseOut won't even let you get to your drop down list.

Comment: I did want to do it to learn (or, relearn really). The setup I'm using already has a separate mobile menu I'm pleased with as well. I'm already using jquery and am using hover parts, which from my understanding is the same as mouseenter/mouseleave.